# photshop cc, 3d feature not visible. Intel (R) hd graphics

Tags: adobe-photoshop, intel-graphics, 3d

Hi I have a toshiba satellite c650 and I installed photoshop CC. and openGL is not working I cannot use the 3D features and cannot use rotate functions.

the specs are as follows

8GB RAM
300GB HDD

my display adapter
Intel(R) HD Graphics

Chip Type: Intel(R) HD Graphics(i3)
Approx total memory: 1696MB
Driver Name: igdumd64.dll,igd10umd64.dll,igdumdx32,igd10umd32

I tried updating the driver but it says that the best and latest driver is already installed. I tried downloading the website from the intel website but could not find out which one would solve my problem. So How would I enable the OpenGl so That I could use my 3d features on my latest photoshop CC.
Thank you.

Comment: You've offer a lot of almost useful info, but nothing that's ACTUALLY usable.  :)  How did you try to update the driver?  Did you try getting the driver from Toshiba's site?  How about Intel? they have a driver detector, did you try that?  What version of the Intel graphics driver is currently installed? What's the EXACT model of your Toshiba?  What's the EXACT Intel HD Graphics chip in your notebook?

Comment: Yes I updated from the toshiba's website because the toshiba graphics driver is customized whereas the drivers from intel site is the more generic one. Yes I tried the detector and they recommend to use the manufactor's driver instead. My graphic chips is simply intel(R) HD graphics. My toshiba model is Satellite C650 - PC12E